# EXPORT 1million rows with 500 column Data into excel from SQL database from application buil using .NET 3.5 framework

Tags: c#, sql, reporting-services, export-to-excel, ssis-2012

Excel report should support 1million rows and 800 columns. The application has to generate excel in two modes 
1.online, where on selecting an entity on grid view excel report has to be generated .
2.offline,user can select multiple entities  and using a button on UI can trigger it to generate excel and can receive excel via mail.

Currently application supports the above functionality ,but the export is very slow .Application and Database is on the same server. Keeping that in mind we have to design a framework where it will be fast even incase of Data on the application is increased by 10x with minimal performance issues.

Does SSIS will serve the purpose or if any other please suggest?

Comment: I am thinking "pivot tables connected to the database".

Comment: That's beyond what i would put into Excel.  1)  How can you use such a large amount of data and 2) how can you expect Excel to consume such a large amount of data? ;-)

Comment: Currently we use open XML. Multiple users upload and export and we have found that since there is large number of exports going on ,especially when export is of data around 20K+ records the application hangs.
Going ahead we expect application has to handle 10x data and performance is the main concern.

Comment: Oh lordy. Jump off that ship!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 million of records definitely will take some time and in a concurrent environment this is not good. It is best to have services oriented architecture, or just execute your code asynchronously to prevent this hanging.
The processing of the export (for example in a service) should run in background threads to handle the load.

When completed generate and send mail as you mentioned.
Or save in an application temp dir and use SignalR for example (or just pooling the server with Ajax) to check if the process in the service has completed. If yes, redirect the client to download the file.

Answer (score 0):

You dont say what the UI is, but since you mention "online" I assume its a browser. Consequently the fastest way would be to query the SQL Server, extract the data set, and use the documented OpenDocument XML to generate an XLSX file as part of the Response Stream being returned by the MVC Controller/Web API. This generates least handling of data, and keeps the text handling on the Web Server.

Comment: Currently we use open XML. Multiple users upload and export and hence there is large number of exports going on ,especially when export is of data around 20K+ records the application hangs.
Going ahead we expect application has to handle 10x data and performance is the main concern.                                                                                                        Currently we generate excel on the server side and send it using mail for offline and incase of online it is downloadable for the user.  we are looking for improvement of framework or any other alternatives.

Comment: You really need to tell us more about where the time is being spent in your application stack. Have you used a Profiler to find out where the time is being spent ? Can you isolate the most expensive processes ? If your applicaiton is already optimally coded and if you are using IIS and the load is on the generation of the XML then just scale out a few more IIS instances on other machines - its the traditional way to cope with a high load once you've eliminated code inefficiency.

Comment: We analyzed the compete flow by breakinging into sections and optimized the costliest ones.It helped.